# handle data in caller or callee?

Tags: coding-style

let's say I have an object in an OO language called `Man`, and `Man` has a property `name`. if I have a function that says hello to this man, should I send `Man.name` as an argument or just send `Man`. for example, in python:

```
def sayHello(Man):
    print 'hello! ' + Man.name

def sayHello2(name):
    print 'hello! ' + name
```

which one is better? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function needs the name, and no other properties of Man, just send the name. The reason is to reduce coupling (sayHello does not need to know the properties of Man).

If your function needs two or more properties of Man, you should probably pass the object. The principal is called "Preserve Whole Object" from Martin Fowler's book *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*.